# Seaborn stacked barplot from an unknown number of columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

This code would display a stacked barplot:

```py
s1 = sns.barplot(x='month', y='col1', data=df, color='blue')
s2 = sns.barplot(x='month', y='col2', data=df, color='red')
```

However, that assumes knowing that numbers are contained in two columns whose name is known.

Now, what about if the the DataFrame is a pivot table, so you don't know in advance either the number of columns (with numbers) or their name?

Comment: Using the sample from the official website as an [example](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/part_whole_bars.html), I confirmed that if the column name is unknown, it can be handled by specifying it with iloc. `sns.barplot(x=crashes.iloc[:,0], y=crashes.iloc[:,7], data=crashes, label="Total", color="b")`

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Any hint on how I can have a different color for each column?

Comment: I think you can do this by creating a list of colors you want to set, and then setting them as colors. `colors=['red','green','blue'];sns.barplot(...,color=colors[0])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-shape your dataframe with [**`pandas.melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html).
Starting from this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']})
df['col1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['col2'] = np.random.random(len(df))
```

```
  month      col1      col2
0   Jan  0.374540  0.058084
1   Feb  0.950714  0.866176
2   Mar  0.731994  0.601115
3   Apr  0.598658  0.708073
4   May  0.156019  0.020584
5   Jun  0.155995  0.969910
```

You can re-shape with:

```
df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = 'month',
             var_name = 'column',
             value_name = 'value')
```

```
   month column     value
0    Jan   col1  0.374540
1    Feb   col1  0.950714
2    Mar   col1  0.731994
3    Apr   col1  0.598658
4    May   col1  0.156019
5    Jun   col1  0.155995
6    Jan   col2  0.058084
7    Feb   col2  0.866176
8    Mar   col2  0.601115
9    Apr   col2  0.708073
10   May   col2  0.020584
11   Jun   col2  0.969910
```

Now you can plot with:

```
sns.barplot(x='month', y='value', data=df, hue='column')
```

Regardless of the number and names of columns of original dataframe.

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']})
df['col1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['col2'] = np.random.random(len(df))

df = pd.melt(frame = df,
             id_vars = 'month',
             var_name = 'column',
             value_name = 'value')

sns.barplot(x='month', y='value', data=df, hue='column')

plt.show()
```

- 2 columns:

  [image]
- 4 columns, same code for melting and plotting:

  [image]

---

In the case you want a stacked barplot, it's even simpler because you don't have to re-shape the dataframe through melt:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun']})
df['col1'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['col2'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['col3'] = np.random.random(len(df))
df['col4'] = np.random.random(len(df))

df.set_index('month').plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: What I want is stacked barplot. The only way I know how to do this is to create one axis for each bar, as illustrated in my question, or as show [here](https://www.python-graph-gallery.com/stacked-and-percent-stacked-barplot).

Comment: No, you don't have to, you can use a simpler code with `df.set_index('month').plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)`, even avoiding to re-shape the dataframe. See my updated answer

Comment: Thanks, that does work indeed. I didn't find the time to try these solutions until now, but it looks like pandas's plot function is the easiest.